# Problema com SSIS e API Rest

Tags: api, visual-studio, ssis

Tenho um problema singular e preciso de ajuda o mais rápido possível. O negócio é o seguinte:
Desenvolvi um aplicativo SSIS usando Visual Studio 2019, mas agora descobri que preciso fazer uma conexão usando API. Como posso fazer isso?

- Não posso usar componentes de terceiros e não posso usar nenhuma dll adicional porque o notebook tem muitos problemas de bloqueio (não consigo nem conectar um mouse USB).
- tentei usar o componente de script, mas descobri que é quase impossível usar sem uma dll externa).

Então é isso. Eu preciso aplicar uma conexão de API ao meu projeto SSIS sem usar nenhuma ferramenta externa, apenas usando ferramentas nativas.
Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

(O post original escrevi em inglês, mas no desespero joguei no translate e acho que deu para entender)